# Partition and permutation using R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, combinatorics, partition

I'm trying to find all possible partitions (including 0) of M into N parts using R. Then, I would like to permutate each outcome without replacement and without repeatition.

For example, for M=4 and N=2, I want to get:

```
[1,] 4 3 2 0 1
[2,] 0 1 2 4 3
```

Now, I can get:

```
[1,] 4 3 2
[2,] 0 1 2
```

using `partitions::restrictedparts(4, 2, include.zero=TRUE)`. How should I continue?

To give some background of this question, I'm actually trying to find all possible outcomes of the number of occurence of each side after rolling a die for 60 times.

Comment: Does this help: `vapply(1:60,   function(x)sample(1:6,1),1)` ?, Again I might  misunderstood your question

Comment: also for your first case, I am unable to related the dice problem with first case, you can do `e <- expand.grid(0:4, 0:4);  e[rowSums(e)==4,]`

Comment: This gives the result of one group of experiments but I would like to know all possible outcomes. @PKumar

Comment: @dis, can you please elaborate little more, what do you mean by all possible outcomes? Do you want to say instead of sum of 4 you can have 1 to 6

Comment: The first case is more like tossing a coin for 4 times, and find all possible combinations of number of occurence of heads and tails. @PKumar

Comment: For the die case, all possible outcomes means something like (55,1,1,1,1,1), (1,55,1,1,1,1),...,(54,2,1,1,1,1), (54,1,2,1,1,1),... @PKumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208363/discussion-between-pkumar-and-dls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function available in the package that you are currently using (i.e. `partitions`) that does just what you are looking for. It is appropriately called `compositions` (See [Composition (combinatorics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) for more information).

```
partitions::compositions(4, 2)

[1,] 4 3 2 1 0
[2,] 0 1 2 3 4
```

Now, to solve your actual problem, we have:

```
myParts <- partitions::compositions(60, 6)  ## Note that include.zero is TRUE by default

dim(myParts)
[1]       6 8259888
```

And here is the output:

```
transMat <- t(as.matrix(myParts))
head(transMat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   60    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]   59    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]   58    2    0    0    0    0
[4,]   57    3    0    0    0    0
[5,]   56    4    0    0    0    0
[6,]   55    5    0    0    0    0

tail(transMat)
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[8259883,]    1    0    0    0    0   59
[8259884,]    0    1    0    0    0   59
[8259885,]    0    0    1    0    0   59
[8259886,]    0    0    0    1    0   59
[8259887,]    0    0    0    0    1   59
[8259888,]    0    0    0    0    0   60
```